# Changing flex box width with javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, flexbox

I'm working on a user interface based largely on flexbox, that can basically be broken down into a content area and a sidebar which can be toggled (its width is changed by adding/removing a class).

When the sidebar is toggled, the content area is manually resized through javascript. It contains an svg canvas which needs to be redrawn, so this cannot be done through CSS. Chrome handles this code perfectly.

Firefox and Safari, however, behave very strangely, and interestingly not in the same way.

I was able to reproduce the behavior in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/q1yp6ssw/21/

It also happens with a regular `<div>`, it's not just `<svg>` as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/mqok5exb/2/

`toggleSidebar()` calls the function `resizeSvg()` which resizes the "svg" element using the size of its parent.

```
function resizeSvg() {
    var width = $svg.parent()[0].offsetWidth;

    $svg.attr('width', width); 
    $svg.find('text')[0].textContent = 'width: ' + width;
}
```

If you're testing these fiddles in Firefox, you'll notice that the content area resizes too early, and becomes larger than it should be, pushing the sidebar outside the container's original dimensions. **Using `setTimeout` to delay the resize did not work.**

It seems to be a problem with timing and when each browser renders the updated size of the parent element. **The behavior is the same without the transition**, so that's not the problem.

My question: What is causing this and how do I fix it, or at the very least find a usable workaround? If it turns out to be a flexbox problem, then flexbox can be replaced.

Thanks!

Comment: You dont even want to see what happens with IE11. Heavily bugs out.

Comment: @JaredT, I was fiddling with it in Chrome and Firefox on a Linux machine and had a friend test it in Safari. I can only image what IE would do with this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I'm trying to do something similar and in my case changing `width` with javascript (angular) results in 50px lower than calculated width.
If you want to set exact value for flex you should set both `width` and `min-width` with your javascript code.

here is a code which solve my problem:

```
el.style.width=String(newWidth)+'px';
el.style.minWidth=String(newWidth)+'px';
```